# pause CSS hover funktion don't pause my slideshow when the mouse is hovered over the slideshow

Tags: html, css, hover, frontend, slideshow

i'm trying to build my first website but stuck with the pause funktion. I wanted to make the slideshow to be on pause when i hover my mouse over it but couldn't figure out a solution yet. You can see what i have done until now. Thanks in advance for help!

https://codepen.io/sadeerthaer/pen/MWgRmmw`enter code here`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post your code here, not just as a link to codepen. If you name specific elements by id or class on which the error occurs you help others to better understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hej hej, If I were you I wouldn't even try implement that kind of functionality using css. If you are willing to learn, look into basic javascript and use a slider plugin like [Slick](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) or [Flickity](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/). They have a bunch of built-in options like autoplay, pause on hover, controls etc etc etc. Todeloo